# How can I download css on Android Chrome page?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been working on the css of a website in wordpress. For some reason, I had a server error on wordpress and I lost all of my css. I did save a cached file on my android and I turned it to airplane mode temporarily to make sure it is working.

In chrome on android, I have set a flag to show cached files when offline.

Is there a way I can use dev tools and grab the css that is being used?

Comment: This is why it is essential use source control (e.g. git), to have a history of changes.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully losing 40 hours of design work via css. I found a solution. Luckily I did have a cached version on my android chrome browser.

My solution:
- Turn Airplane Mode on Android to disable the cache from being updated to the latest.
- In the android chrome browser, navigated to: chrome://flags and enabled the show offline pages flag.
- I then navigated to the chrome://cache and located the desired style.css file and copied and pasted the url. Chrome then displayed a button to show the cached version. The style.css code displayed correctly, and I copy and pasted the code and sent it via email. 
- Applied the css code to my wordpress site....worked flawless.